# how to use fetch with express to send data to express server that is using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I am getting a POST http://localhost:3000/handledata 500 (Internal Server Error)
when I am trying to post some data that I need to handle on the backend , below is the code for my front and backend anything missing ? or is there something wrong ? why would the post post to port 3000 instead of 5000 ? in my package.json I am calling a proxy is this even related to the error ?

```js
// Fetch front end call 
fetch('/handledata', {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2 }),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
      
// Express server 
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
//import cors from 'cors'
import CryptoJs from 'crypto-js';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = 5000; //process.env.PORT || 5000;

const router = express.Router();
// Test server 
app.get('/test', (request: any, response: any) => {
  response.send('working......................');
});

// Post data to handle
app.post('/handledata', (req: any, res: any) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const handeleddata = // handledata logic could be anything ! 
  res.json(handeleddata);
});



app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server Started on Port ${PORT}`)!);
```

```js
frontend package.json

{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^7.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/html2canvas": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.26",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.13",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.7",
    "firestore-size": "^2.0.7",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.3",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "notistack": "^1.0.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Backend package.json

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.4",
    "npm": "6.14.14"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"nodemon src/index.ts\" \"npm run client\"",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "client": "file:client",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.6",
    "npm": "^8.1.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your fetch request API url to give the complete hostname:

```js
 fetch('http://localhost:5000/handledata')
```

also you need to setup the cors in your backend

```js
app.use(cors());
```